# Ubuntu 16 dual-boot Boot install error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I am trying to install ubuntu-16 along side Windows 10 on HP-Probook. Every time I try to install, i get the following grub error [Present Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81qOc.jpg). I made the bootable USB using rufus,opted for GPT partition.

I installed keeping the wifi ON, as has been mentioned at many other places,but still it didn't work out. Some days ago, I used to get the following error but now the error comes in boot loading[Earlier Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWSTe.jpg). I have set the fast boot and secure boot off.

I tried running the boot repair in Ubuntu once and It messed up my Windows 10 booting also.When I install Ubuntu 15, I get a similar boot error, The error message isn't exactly the same,though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably caused by the Windows feature known as Fast Startup. See [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) for information on how to shut it off. You may need to also disable Hibernate, as described [here.](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) These features cause filesystems open in Windows to be left in an inconsistent state in other OSes, which is highly dangerous. In your specific case, the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) is shared between OSes, and so is probably left in a state in which it cannot be written from Ubuntu, producing the error.

After you disable Fast Startup and Hibernate, you should reboot once or twice. You then have several options for recovery. The three simplest are probably:

- Run the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) utility. This should install GRUB, which is the step that's failed, and you should be good to go.
- Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) prepare a boot medium with it, and boot with it. You can then install rEFInd via its Debian package or PPA, and your system should then work. Note, however, that if Secure Boot is active, you'll need to either jump through extra hoops or disable it for this approach to work.
- Re-install Ubuntu, being careful to delete or completely overwrite the existing Ubuntu installation. (Automatic settings might result in a duplicate installation, which you probably don't want.)

Note that you need to do only *one* of these three things. (Of course, if you try one and it fails, you can try another one.)

Comment: Os's install even if hibernation is on.. doesn't matter...problem will come while mounting disks..i think op installed Ubuntu in Different boot option and messed grub with boot repair.. else rufus is the one who makes this stuff sometimes..once i had exact similar situation turning on or off secure boot solved my problem :/

Comment: I've heard of cases in which Windows leaves the ESP in a bad enough state that Linux can't mount it, which would produce this problem. The fact that the computer was reporting filesystem errors on a FAT filesystem strongly suggests that there's a problem with the ESP (which uses FAT).

Comment: Make sure Windows fast start up is off. You may still need chkdsk from Windows on ESP or dosfsck. Must be unmounted
`sudo dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/sdb1` change sdb1 to whichever partition is your ESP. See also `man dosfsck`